# SharePoint 2010 Lists - Totals at Bottom of List Instead of Top of List

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a simple way to cause the column totals (like Sum) to appear at the end of a list instead of at the top of the list? Having them at the top just seems unnatural...

Thanks

Lonnie Tyre

Answer (score 2):

You can move the totals to the bottom as described [here](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/moving-totals-to-the-bottom-of-the-view/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably venture to guess that this was done because some lists may be large and span multiple pages and it could take quite a while to find out how many items are on a list.

However, you do have options.  If you are code-savy, you can enlist the SPList.ItemCount Property and get your answer.  From there you can put it anywhere you please.  I have done it for custom web part development where the count drove certain things.  For instance, maybe you would like to fire some event or change the style of something on the page based on how many tasks a user has assigned to them.  You can get that information a few different ways but this is just one.

I'd look into possibly creating your own display forms if you have a strong enough desire.  I have done that in SPD a few times.

Good luck!